# Trigger download after clicking on submit on webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm looking for a way on how I could download an uploaded file from the node once the user has click submit on the webform.

[image]

Here is a sample of the webform

[image]

Confirmation settings doesn't offer a setting that can download a file after trigger. I can attach link to download the file but I would like the file to trigger automatically once user submits the form

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of achieving your goal.

1. On after submit page, add a link to your file by adding the `download` attribute.

   `<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUohe.png" download>Download the file</a>`

   Then, add some JS to force the download.
2. You can create a [webform submit Handler](//cornel.co/article/create-webform-submit-handler) where you can implement advanced stuff.

Answer (score 1):

May you could inject a little JavaScript into the Webform and redirect the user to the file download.

Or set the webform's confirmation redirect to point to the uploaded file.